# strlen игнорируется

Tags: php, strlen

Мне нужно проверить, не пустая ли форма. если пустая или меньше 10, то ошибка.
пробовал strlen(), mb_strlen(utf8_decode())... ни в какую.
После нажатия на кнопку, добавляется пустая запись :(

```
$msg_box = "";
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mess']))
{
    $name = text($_POST['name']) ;
    $mess = text($_POST['mess']) ;
    $rw = intval($_POST['rw']);

        if ($name=='' || mb_strlen(utf8_decode($name))<=2) {$errors[] = 'ПОМИЛКА!<br />Коротке і\'мя';}
        if ($mess=='' || mb_strlen(utf8_decode($mess))<=10) {$errors[] = 'ПОМИЛКА<br />Короткий відгук';}
        $errors = array();
        if(empty($errors))
        {
                $q = DB::$dbs->prepare("INSERT INTO `book` (`name`, `mess`, `rw`, `time`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                $q->execute([$name,$mess,$rw,time()]);
        }
    else
        {

            foreach($errors as $one_error)
            {
                $msg_box .= '<div class="bg-danger text-center">'.$one_error.'</div>';
            }
        }
}
```

echo $msg_box;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($name=='' || mb_strlen(utf8_decode($name))<=2) {$errors[] = 'ПОМИЛКА!<br />Коротке і\'мя';}
if ($mess=='' || mb_strlen(utf8_decode($mess))<=10) {$errors[] = 'ПОМИЛКА<br />Короткий відгук';}
$errors = array();
```

При выполнение условия,вы добавляете сообщение о ошибке в массив $errors,
дальше почему то вы его пересоздаете.

Удалите или переместите в начало

```
$errors = array();
```